# How to put an image file into a MemoryStream and attach it into an Email

Tags: c#, email, encryption, email-attachments, memorystream

I encrypted an image,
Now I need to read that image, decrypt and attach it into an email.

For first step I try to put an image file and attach it into an Email,
but when i receive email, the attached image is corrupted !

I try many different ways, but without success.
(I created windows application project just for test, Eventually I need to use solution in MVC Web Application project)

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var filePath = "D:\\3.jpg"; // path to none encrypted image file

    var ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));

    // Create attachment
    var attach = new Attachment(ms, new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg));
    attach.ContentDisposition.FileName = "sample.jpg";

    // Send Email
    IMailSender mailSender = new MailSender();
    var isSuccess = mailSender.Send(
      "sample email title",
      "sample@gmail.com",
      "sample subject",
      "sample body",
      new Attachment[] { attach });

    MessageBox.Show(isSuccess ? "Email sent successfully" : mailSender.ErrorMessage);

}
```

Comment: after you load image to stream did you set the seek position right? ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (MailMessage Message = new MailMessage())
{
    Message.From = new MailAddress("from@mail.com");
    Message.Subject = "My Subject";
    Message.Body = "My Body";
    Message.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@mail.com"));

    //Attach more file
    foreach (var item in Attachment)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));

        Attachment Data = new Attachment(ms, "FileName");
        ContentDisposition Disposition = Data.ContentDisposition;
        Disposition.CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-5);
        Disposition.ModificationDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-5);
        Disposition.ReadDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-5);
        Data.ContentType = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
        Message.Attachments.Add(Data);
    }

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("SmtpAddress", "SmtpPort");
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("SmtpUser", "SmtpPassword");
    await smtp.SendMailAsync(Message);
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your help. I add `ContentDisposition Disposition = Data.ContentDisposition;
        Disposition.CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-5);
        Disposition.ModificationDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-5);
        Disposition.ReadDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-5);` in my codes and it works fine. thanks a lot